# "Build" builds my project, "Build Solution" doesn't

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

I've just started using VS2010. I've got a largish solution that migrated successfully from VS2008. I've added a console application project called "Test" to the solution. Selecting **build->build solution** does not compile the new project. Selecting **build->build Test** does build the project. In the failure case, no error is given.

Similarly, setting this project as the startup project and pressing F5 to start debugging also fails to compile.

I'm upset by this. Can anyone calm me down by telling me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but today I installed AnhkSVN 2.1.8420 (latest version).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure the solution configuration is set to build your new project.

Go to Build | Configuration Manager  and see if the build checkbox is set for your project

Comment: You rock. Thanks. Will accept when allowed. Any idea why this isn't checked by default in VS2010?

Comment: It's not just VS 2010. I have seen it with VS08 too. When adding a new project to an existing solution it isn't always set to build. I am not sure what the conditions are that cause this. Haven't really looked in to it much

Answer (score 0):

For me it was incorrect build order. Right click on the `solution` and click on `Project Build Order...`. If anything is built in the wrong order switch to tab `Dependencies` and set correct values. After this everything worked for me.