# Visual Studio 2012 not building dependent projects

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2012

I just upgraded a VS2010 project to VS2012 and am now having a problem where dependent projects are not building on demand.  For instance, say I have the following projects in my solution:

- Library A
- ConsoleApp 1

Where ConsoleApp 1 references Library A.  If I change the signature of a method in a class in Library A and run ConsoleApp 1, there will be a compiler error due to ConsoleApp 1 not seeing my changes because running ConsoleApp 1 did NOT cause Library A to build.

If I manually build Library A, then manually build ConsoleApp 1, it works fine.  However, I would expect that running ConsoleApp 1 should cause any dependent projects to be rebuilt before launching.

Could I have something configured incorrectly?  Or is this a bug in VS2012?

Comment: It may be a bug, cause VS 2012 is still in the RC stage... Can't tell for sure though...

Comment: What is displayed in your project dependencies (right click on project, then pick project dependencies)?

Comment: Project dependencies look correct.  eg. for ConsoleApp 1, the checkbox for Library A is checked.  The problem may be worse than I thought.  If I make a change DIRECTLY to a class in ConsoleApp 1, then hit F5/Run, ConsoleApp 1 does NOT rebuild and it executes the last built version, without my changes.

Comment: I still get this problem with VS2012 Update 3. Bring back VS6 ffs!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try by removing project `references` and adding them again (path to follow: `References ->` (right click) `Add reference -> Solution -> Project`). Before giving another try `Save All`. This is how I solved it.

Comment: So, this wasn't exactly the problem, but I ended up removing ALL projects from the solution, editing the .csproj files to remove the project references, then adding each project back into the solution and recreating the references.  Seems to work fine now!

Comment: I had the same problem last night/this morning. So I removed ALL the project from the solution, added them all back, adding project references at each stage to get it to build and all is well.

Comment: The two above comments worked for me. Removing all projects from the solution and manually adding them (building as I went). Winner!!!

Answer (score 51):

Your symptoms sound very similar to [those I experienced a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026463/build-builds-my-project-build-solution-doesnt). Ensure that the projects are set to build with your current `active` solution `configuration` and active solution platform under `Build->Configuration Manager`.

Comment: This did it for me; I was getting the error in release mode, and the checkboxes for each project was off.  +1

Comment: Nice. I had `Any CPU` selected and nothing worked. I just switched the active solution configuration to `Mixed Platforms`and now dependent projects are built again.

Comment: That was exactly what happened for me! I had it while migrating from Xamarin Studio Mac to Visual Studio Mac. For some reason it lost the original configs.. :/

Comment: After hours of frustration! Thank you. In my case, I build the project successfully on my machine, but it was failing on VSTS. It turned out that the build definition on VSTS was using "Relaese" for "Active solution Configuration", while I was building locally using "Debug". Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

This happens when the .suo file for the solution becomes locked and Visual Studio is no longer able to write to it. Another symptom of this problem is that you will see temp suo files being created next to the solution when you open it. Try closing Visual Studio and deleting all *.suo files in your working area. Then reopen Visual Studio and rebuild all. No need to manually rebuild your solution. This will fix the issue when it is caused by a locked .suo, as happened to a colleague of mine today.

In his case, the cause seemed to be that he shutdown his laptop while Visual Studio was still open. Maybe the shutdown of Windows didn't complete cleanly? We can only speculate on how the .suo originally became locked.

Comment: In my case I did not actually checked if .suo file was locked. I just kept on seeing build errors flowing around after the build succeeded, and also Visual Studio messing up code when performing some Rename refactoring. I deleted the bigger one of the two .suo files next to solution (was the .v12.suo), and build errors seem gone now.

Comment: this fixed my problem

Answer (score 8):

I tried all the solutions above and that did not fix the issue for me. I found that it was because of the `Active configuration` in the `ConfigurationManager` was set to build only the Main (start up) project.

Go to `Build` > `ConfigurationManager`

Ensure that all the projects you want to build are checked as in the screenshot below
This is a similar issue on Asp.Net forum [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/996113.aspx/1) and this is the details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx) 
. Although it was weired, bcoz I never changed these settings and it was working properly last week
[image]

Answer (score 6):

I've encountered a similar problem, the solution (or the probelem) were the `Build and Run` settings under `Tools > Options... > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run` where "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" was checked. The screenshot shows my currently working solution.

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Options]

Comment: For me, visual studio was very confused, so I unchecked this box and rebuilt and all the errors went away.  I rechecked the box and did a rebuild and all seems to be working again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I resolve the issue by right clicking on the project; Build Dependencies > Project Dependencies. Then manually setting the order for each project. very painful if you have a lot of projects.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the referencing project has same or higher .Net framework version than the referenced project.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click solution in solution explorer then click "Clean Solution".