# Forced to Rebuild Project Depedencies in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012

I recently upgraded to VS.NET 2012 and I started encountering a very frustrating issue when debugging.

Project A has a project reference to Project B. When I edit Project B, I would expect that action of building/debugging Project A to detect the change in Project B and automatically include it during the build of Project A. (That's kinda the point of project dependencies.) And that's exactly what used to happen in VS 2010.

But this doesn't happen in 2012. Indeed, even if I build Project B explicitly, Project A will not pick up that change unless I *rebuild* project A.

So now I'm forced to explicitly build Project B then go back to Project A and explicitly rebuild it for the modifications in Project B to be included.

Thoughts?

Comment: What kinds of projects are these?  What kind of changes exhibit this problem?  (E.g., when you edit Project B, do you actually make changes to it that require A to be rebuilt?)

Comment: One is a Windows Forms application (project A) and one is a DLL (project B). Yes, I'm making changes (code changes) that should force a build on project A.

Answer (score 6):

Did you set the dependency projects in your solution?

We can set them from:

Right click solution->Properties->Project Dependencies

By the way, did you build your solution in the Visual Studio IDE or by msbuild command?

If you use msbuild to build the projects, you should add DependsOnTargets attribute in your project files.

More information you can refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Project A has a depednency on Project B. This was automatically setup by VS.NET, and I just double checked it.

Answer (score 3):

Your 3rd paragraph seems to indicate a misunderstanding with the way dependencies work. Forgive me if I am mistaken.

If project A has a dependency on project B, building project B would not force a rebuild of project A. Building project A however should check for changes in project B and rebuild B automatically if needed.

Project A in this case is the parent or root project. Building the parent would check all the projects on which it depends and rebuild them if they are out of date. Always building the parent would automatically build outdated dependencies first, and then the parent project would be built picking up any new changes in the dependencies.

```
A
 \
  B
  |\
  C D
```

In this example, if B had dependencies they would be built as well. If you explicitly built B, its dependencies C and D would be checked and rebuilt but not A.

If you explicitly built A, first C and D would be checked and rebuilt if necessary, then B, then finally A.

Comment: I don't believe I have any misunderstanding. As I said, I make changes in project B. I then build project A and the changes in project B do not get included. My point about building/rebuilding was only to illustrate my current work around, not to describe how I would expect it to work. Your explaination still does not tell me why building project A after I've made changes to project B doesn't result in those changes being included.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem before, and the cause was that the A's reference to B was a regular reference (to the DLL file), rather than a "Project Reference".  This situation would certainly explain the behaviour you see.

To check, look at `ProjectA.csproj` in a text editor, and examine all the `<Reference>` and `<ProjectReference>` elements to make sure they are the way you think they should be.

Comment: If this isn't the problem then something's wrong with the project file or Visual Studio has issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a continuous integration (CI) server. A CI can be configured to monitor source repositories and triggered to build target assemblies when new changes have been committed to the code base.

Otherwise, as others have mentioned, project dependencies can be used to rebuild referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause of this is locked .suo files. See my answer on this question:

[Visual Studio 2012 not building dependent projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064345/visual-studio-2012-not-building-dependent-projects/13571220#13571220)